# How to Check for Collision in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

I tried to make some code run when two boxes collide with each other in Pygame, but somehow it is not working.

Game Declarations

```
class coin:
def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.x2 = x + width
    self.y2 = y + height
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
x = 50
y = 50
width = 20
height = 20
x2 = x + width
y2 = y + height
vel = 10
newCoin = coin(0,0,0,0)
needCoin = True

def generateCoin():
    randX = math.floor(random.random() * 100)
    randY = math.floor(random.random() * 100)
    print(randX)
    print(randY)
    return coin(randX, randY, 10, 10)
```

Game Display

```
if ((x < newCoin.x2) and (newCoin.x < x2) and (y2 > newCoin.y) and (newCoin.y2 > y)):
        print("Colliding")
        needCoin = True
        pygame.time.delay(100)

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,255,0), (newCoin.x,newCoin.y,newCoin.width,newCoin.height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and [`.coliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect):

```py
coin_rect = pygame.Rect(newCoin.x, newCoin.y, newCoin.width, newCoin.height)
rect_2 = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)

if coin_rect.colliderect(rect_2):
    print("Colliding")
    needCoin = True
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```

If you want to make your code work, then you have to ensure that `self.x2`, `self.y2` respectively `x2` and `y2` is up to date. That you have to update this variables when ever `self.x`, `self.y` respectively `x`, `y` changes.

---

Anyway I recommend to use `pygame.Rect` instead of `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`:

```py
class coin:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, height, width)

def generateCoin():
    randX = math.floor(random.random() * 100)
    randY = math.floor(random.random() * 100)
    print(randX)
    print(randY)
    return coin(randX, randY, 10, 10)

test_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 20, 20)
vel = 10
newCoin = generateCoin()
needCoin = True
```

```py
if newCoin.rect.colliderect(test_rect):
    print("Colliding")
    needCoin = True
    pygame.time.delay(100)

pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,255,0), newCoin.rect)
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you